# How to fill an array if its size is apriori unknown

Tags: java, arrays, dynamic, integer, fill

How to avoid `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` if the size of `indexes` is apriori unknown?

```
Integer[] indexes = new Integer[]{};
int num = 0;
for (ArrayList<Integer[]> arr: list) {
   for (int i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
       indexes[num] = arr[i];
       num++;
   }
}
```

The goal is to get a one-dimensional array `Integer[] indexes` from a two-dimensional array `ArrayList<Integer[]> list`.

**UPDATE**:

For instance:

```
list[0] = {1,2,3}
list[1] = {4}
```

I need to get:

```
indexes = {1,2,3,4}
```

Comment: I know it's incorrect. Therefore I asked how to avoid an error and correct this code.

Comment: Is `list`, a list of `Integer[]`s? `arr.length` is wrong because `ArrayList` does not have `.length`.

Comment: @KlausosKlausos With this extra information I have updated my response with some steps to get exactly what you want

Comment: @βнɛƨн Ǥʋяʋиɢ: for (Integer[] arr: list)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a new `ArrayList` (`newList.add(arr[i])`) and then call `toArray()`:

```
Integer[] indexes = newList.toArray(new Integer[newList.size()]);
```

A less effective solution that doesn't use an intermediate list - you can loop the whole structure once just to count the elements. Then instantiate the array with the precalculated size.

Comment: DO you offer to use: Object[] indexes = list.toArray()? I tried it, but it provides a two-dimensional array 'indexes'.

Comment: not `list.toArray()`. Use a new list where you store the indexes

Answer (score 1):

A few approaches spring to mind:

1. Run through an ArrayList that will grow appropriately, and then use .toArray() once complete. This isn't memory efficient.
2. Iterate over **arr** and calculate the max size, form the array at that size, then reiterate populating.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `list` is defined as follows:

```
List<Integer[]> list = new ArrayList<Integer[]>();
```

you can do:

```
List<Integer> indexList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for (Integer[] arr: list) {
    indexList.addAll(Arrays.asList(arr));
}
```

and finally convert to array:

```
Integer[] indexes = indexList.toArray(new Integer[indexList.size()]{});
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot. When initializing an array you have to specify its size. So if you do not know the size, you can either opt for declaring an array with a very large size and hoping that everything will fit into it (with all associated drawbacks like memory overhead, array.length which becomes quite useless, ... ). Or you can opt to use an `ArrayList` which uses internally an array but is smart enough to increase its size when needed.

You can achieve this as well by using arrays by copying your array into another bigger array when needed, but then you are basically rewriting the `ArrayList`.

In case you need to convert the list later on back to an array you can use the [`toArray`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#toArray%28T%5b%5d%29) method

EDIT:

a small update based on the extra information in the question. If you have to convert an `ArrayList<Integer[]>` into a one dimension array you can use the following steps

1. Create a new `ArrayList<Integer>`
2. Loop over your existing list (which contains `Integer[]`) and use the [`Collections#addAll`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#addAll%28java.util.Collection,%20T...%29) method to add all the elements of the array into your new List
3. Convert your list to an array with the `toArray` method

Answer (score 0):

1. Don't initialize the array as `Integer[] indexes = new Integer[]{};`

You're making it an array of length zero.  What you should do instead is this:

```
int maxNum=0;
for (ArrayList<Integer[]> arr: list) {

    maxNum += arr.length;

}

Integer[] indexes = new Integer[maxNum];
num=0;
for (ArrayList<Integer[]> arr: list) {
   for (int i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
       indexes[num+i] = arr[i];

   }
   num+=arr.length;
}
```

What I've done there is determine the maximum array size, and then initialized the array.

After that I populate it with each array in the `ArrayList`, offsetting  my input by the value of the previous array.

With that said, there are more efficient methods to do this, but if you HAVE to have an `ArrayList` of `Integer[]`s, this is how I would do it.

Answer (score 0):

add every thing to single ArrayList and make an array of it using  [T[] toArray(T[] a)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#toArray%28T%5B%5D%29) or [Object[] toArray()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#toArray%28%29) ... the firstmethod is typesafe, the array provided can but musst not be of length needed, it will be reallocated if its length is shorter than the size of the list